# Изменение нескольких состояний React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

https://codepen.io/st-iv/pen/jJPKyj

В элементе rating-main будет отображаться выбранный рейтинг. 
Прошу помочь решить несколько задач:

1. Каждый клик по одному из трёх состояний сохраняется в rating-main и получается такая ситуация:

   `class="rating-item rating-main rating-bad rating-good rating-great"`

Как избавиться от такого переполнения и сохранять только актуальное состояние?

2. Посоветуйте как при hover на один из 3 вариантов передавать hover элементу rating-main

   ```
   class Rating extends React.Component {
     state = {
     bad: false,
     good: false,
     great: false
   };

   // color states functions

   badSet = () => {
     this.setState({
       bad: true
     });
   };

   goodSet = () => {
     this.setState({
       good: true
     });
   };

   greatSet = () => {
     this.setState({
       great: true
     });
   };

   render() {
   const { bad, good, great } = this.state;
   let classMain = "rating-main";

   // add class on click

   if (bad) {
     classMain += " rating-bad";
   }

   if (good) {
     classMain += " rating-good";
   }

   if (great) {
     classMain += " rating-great";
   }

   return (
     <div className="rating">
       <div className={`rating-item ${classMain}`} />
       <div className="row">
         <div className="rating-item rating-bad" onClick={this.badSet}/>
         <div className="rating-item rating-good" onClick={this.goodSet}/>
         <div className="rating-item rating-great" onClick={this.greatSet}/>
       </div>
     </div>
       );
     }
   }

   class App extends React.Component {
   render() {
     return <Rating />;
    }
   }

   ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
   ```

Comment: https://codepen.io/st-iv/pen/jJPKyj

Comment: @Dantessss Правкой вы поставили вопрос в очередь на переоткрытие. Вы считаете его надо открыть заново? Почему?

Comment: @0xdb Я вносил правку до закрытия вопроса, подправил форматирование текста. Не думаю, это повлияло на содержание

Answer (score 1):

Если выбрать можно только одно состояние (bad,great, good), то можете просто на клик все остальные состояния устанавливать в false

```
badSet = () => {
    this.setState({
      bad: true,
      good:false,
      great:false,
    });
  };

  goodSet = () => {
    this.setState({
      good: true,
      great:false,
      bad:false,
    });
  };

  greatSet = () => {
    this.setState({
      great: true,
      bad:false,
      good:false,
    });
  };
```

Что касается второго вопроса, то если просто нужно сделать тоже самое только на ховер, то замените везде событие `onClick` на `onMouseEnter` :

```
<div className="rating-item rating-bad" onMouseEnter ={this.badSet}></div>
```

В более общем случае для этого можно использовать одну переменную для хранения активного состояния, массив для состояний в виде классов, и data атрибут для управления состоянием:

```js
class Rating extends React.Component {
  state = {
    active:-1,
    rating:[
      "rating-bad",
      "rating-good",
      "rating-great",
    ]
  };

 setActive=(event)=>{
   
   this.setState({
          active:event.currentTarget.dataset.id
   })

 }

  render() {

    let classMain="";
    if(this.state.active!=-1){
      classMain = this.state.rating[this.state.active];
    }

    return (
      <div className="rating">
        <div className={`rating-item ${classMain}`} />
        <div className="row">
          {this.state.rating.map((item,key)=>(
<div data-id={key} className={`rating-item ${this.state.rating[key]}`} onClick={this.setActive}></div>
))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Rating />;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.rating {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.rating-item {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.rating-bad {
  background: red;
}

.rating-good {
  background: yellow;
}

.rating-great {
  background: green;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Хороший ответ, можно только добавить что для работы с классами удобнее использовать [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames)

Comment: а если больше состояний будет, к примеру 9? 
как можно оставить одно нужное, а остальные убрать?

Comment: @stiv для этого можно использовать одну переменную для хранения активного состояния, массив для состояний в виде классов, и `data` атрибут для  управления состоянием. Что-то вроде такого https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wOKedv

Comment: А если в один из raiting item вставить текст или иконку, то при клике raiting item в главный rating добавляется класс undefined. Получается, дополнительные элементы мешают клику, который передает класс. Как это решить?

Comment: @stiv изменил ответ. Для этого вместо `event.target` нужно использовать `event.currentTarget`